# codeigniter custom form validation wont work

Tags: regex, forms, codeigniter, validation

I have a input form and I want to check for some user_name properties. For instance if username is only lowercase with numbers. I am using callback function but given only a simple string such as "a" wont return true .. I really dont understand. What am I doing wrong ??

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('user_name','User name','required|callback_validate_user_name');

...

if($this->form_validation->run() !== false){
    $data['main_content'] = 'pages/news_page';
    $this->load->view('templates/home_body_content', $data);            
} else {
    echo "Damn!";
}

function validate_user_name($user_name){
    if(preg_match('/a/', $user_name) === true){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Where exactly do you define the `validate_user_name` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, PHP `preg_match()` returns `1` if the `pattern` matches given `subject` [[Reference]](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

So use `=== 1` or `== TRUE` instead of `=== true`.

Second, callback function should return `FALSE` when `/a/` pattern is occurred, and return `TRUE` if not.

Comment: Thanks I'm just starting with php the `===` and `==` confuses me a little, I finally created the regex I wanted and its like `'/^[a-z][\-\.a-z0-9]*$/'` it works! for now :D